# Subir archivo a una carpeta recién creada en un servidor ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ftp

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo a una carpeta que se crea en tiempo de ejecución en el servidor FTP
Ósea que al momento de crear la carpeta, el archivo que seleccione se suba a esa carpeta
Si alguien tiene una forma de hacerlo estaría muy agradecido
Este es mi código para crear una nueva carpeta

```
//Creacion de carpeta
public void CreateDirectory()
    {
        string Path = txtNombre.Text;
        string archivo = ftpFileUpload.FileName;
        string filename = Path;
        FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://servidor" + filename );
        ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();
    }
```

Este es mi codigo para subir el archivo seleccionado al servidor ftp
//subir archivo a servidor FTP
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (ftpFileUpload.HasFile)
{
CreateDirectory();

```
            string filename = ftpFileUpload.FileName;
            string path = txtNombre.Text;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path));

            Stream fs = ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

            string filePath = path + filename;
            File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), bytes);

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://servidor" + filename);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            byte[] fileContents;

            using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
            {
                fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            }
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca hay un pequeño codigo que puedes tomar como ejemplo :

```
// Establecer la información de conexión
var request = (SftpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("sftp://hostname/ruta/en/el/servidor/nombre_del_archivo");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Sftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

// Leer el archivo local
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("ruta/al/archivo", FileMode.Open))
{
    // Obtener el flujo de salida de la solicitud
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Copiar el archivo local al flujo de salida de la solicitud
        fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
}

// Obtener la respuesta de la solicitud
using (var response = (SftpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    // Verificar si la transferencia fue exitosa
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.FtpStatusCode.ClosingData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Archivo subido exitosamente.");
    }
}
```